# Excel - convert text to formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having an Excel reference file where I am storing an Excel Pivot formula - the `GETPIVOTDATA()` as text. I am then writing a `VLookup` in another file to get this formula from the reference sheet and convert the text `[GETPIVOTDATA()]` to a formula so that the result of the formula is updated in a specific cell.  I am able to get the result of the `Vlookup`, but unable to convert it into a formula. I have tried `INDIRECT` and `EVALUATE` functions, but nothing works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Append a `=` to the beginning of your formula text and try again?

Comment: Nope, it didn't help

Comment: sample data, screenshot, your formula?

Comment: =FORMULATEXT(A1). Does this help?